# hadoop/hdfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory(hadoop/hdfs/data/) does not exist or is not accessible

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, nodes

I have tried all the different solutions provided at stackoverflow on this topic, but of no help
Asking again with the specific log and the details

Any help is appreciated

I have one master node and 5 slave nodes in my Hadoop cluster. ubuntu user and ubuntu group is the owner of the `~/Hadoop` folder
Both the `~/hadoop/hdfs/data` & `~/hadoop/hdfs/name` folder exist

and permission for both the folders are set to `755`

successfully formated the namenode before starting the script `start-all.sh`

THE SCRIPT FAILS TO LAUNCH THE "NAMENODE"

These are running at the master node

```
ubuntu@master:~/hadoop/bin$ jps

7067 TaskTracker
6914 JobTracker
7237 Jps
6834 SecondaryNameNode
6682 DataNode

ubuntu@slave5:~/hadoop/bin$ jps

31438 TaskTracker
31581 Jps
31307 DataNode
```

Below is the log from name-node log files.

```
..........
..........
.........

014-12-03 12:25:45,460 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2014-12-03 12:25:45,461 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered.
2014-12-03 12:25:45,532 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
2014-12-03 12:25:45,532 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2014-12-03 12:25:45,532 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2.0% max memory = 1013645312
2014-12-03 12:25:45,532 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
2014-12-03 12:25:45,532 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=2097152, actual=2097152
2014-12-03 12:25:45,588 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=ubuntu
2014-12-03 12:25:45,588 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup
2014-12-03 12:25:45,588 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true
2014-12-03 12:25:45,622 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100
2014-12-03 12:25:45,623 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s)
2014-12-03 12:25:45,716 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean
2014-12-03 12:25:45,777 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: dfs.namenode.edits.toleration.length = 0
2014-12-03 12:25:45,777 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times 
2014-12-03 12:25:45,785 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory /home/ubuntu/hadoop/file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop/hdfs/name does not exist
2014-12-03 12:25:45,787 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /home/ubuntu/hadoop/file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop/hdfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)
2014-12-03 12:25:45,801 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /home/ubuntu/hadoop/file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop/hdfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:395)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:299)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Removed the "file:" from the hdfs-site.xml file

[WRONG HDFS-SITE.XML]

```
  <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
  <value>file:/home/hduser/mydata/hdfs/namenode</value>
  </property>
  <property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
  <value>file:/home/hduser/mydata/hdfs/datanode</value>
  </property>
```

[CORRECT HDFS-SITE.XML]

```
  <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
  <value>/home/hduser/mydata/hdfs/namenode</value>
  </property>


  <property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
  <value>/home/hduser/mydata/hdfs/datanode</value>
  </property>
```

Thanks to [Erik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2664547/erik-schmiegelow) for the help.

Comment: I am using above hdfs-site.xml from last 2 years and it is working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Kumar. It was helpful. I removed "file:" from your answer and the error was removed.

Comment: When not using `file:` in the path, `hdfs namenode -format` complains about incorrect path.

Answer (score 7):

Follow the below steps,

1.Stop all services

2.Format your namenode

3.Delete your data node directory

4.start all services

Comment: Thanks, I ran into the same problem today. This fixed everything.

Comment: Where is the data node directory?

Answer (score 6):

run these commands on terminal

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir -p mydata/hdfs/namenode
$ mkdir -p mydata/hdfs/datanode
```

give permission to both directory 755

then,

Add this property in conf/hdfs-site.xml

```
  <property>
 <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
 <value>file:/home/hduser/mydata/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>


<property>
 <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
 <value>file:/home/hduser/mydata/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
```

if not work ,then

```
stop-all.sh
start-all.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the logs: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory /home/ubuntu/hadoop/file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop/hdfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible; I don't think /home/ubuntu/hadoop/file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop/hdfs/name is the correct. It should only be file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop/hdfs/name. do you have any idea from where is it additional bit appended?

Comment: Changed the XML tags. Still the same problem.... its looking for /home/ubuntu/hadoop/hadoop-data/dfs/name folder, whereas, I have my name folder in /home/ubuntu/hadoop/hdfs/name. How to change this configuration

Answer (score 3):

1) name node directory you should be owner and give chmod 750 appropriately
2)stop all services
3)use hadoop namenode -format to format namenode
4)add this to hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>path/to/hadooptmpfolder/dfs/name/data</value> 
    <final>true</final> 
    </property> 
    <property> 
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>path/to/hadooptmpfolder/dfs/name</value> 
    <final>true</final> 
</property>
```

5) to run `hadoop namenode -format`
add `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/bin/` in ~/.bashrc 
wherever hadoop is unzip add that in path

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem, I formatted the namenode then started it

```
Hadoop namenode -format
hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
```

Comment: `$HOADOOP_HOME/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode -format`

and then

`$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode`

Answer (score 0):

You can follow given below steps to remove this error:

1. Stop all hadoop daemons
2. Delete all files from given below directory:
   /tmp/hadoop-{user}/dfs/name/current and /tmp/hadoop-{user}/dfs/data/current
   where user is the user with which you logged in into the box.
3. Format namenode
4. Start all services
5. You will now see a new file VERSION created in directory /tmp/hadoop-/dfs/name/current

One thing to notice here is that value of Cluster ID in file /tmp/hadoop-eip/dfs/name/current/VERSION must be same as in /tmp/hadoop-eip/dfs/data/current/VERSION

-Hitesh