# Hadoop 2.9.0 datanode not running

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I am following [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html) tutorial to set up Hadoop-2.9.0 When I execute the following command:

```
sbin/start-df.sh
```

I get the following output on terminal:

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/uname/hadoop-2.9.0/logs/hadoop-uname-namenode-mname.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/uname/hadoop-2.9.0/logs/hadoop-uname-datanode-mname.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/uname/hadoop-2.9.0/logs/hadoop-uname-secondarynamenode-mname.out
```

Then when I try to copy things as per the tutorial [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html) using the following command

`bin/hdfs dfs -put etc/hadoop input`

I get the following error:

```
put: File /user/uname/input/yarn-site.xml._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

Following code block is the detailed stack trace of the above error. You can ignore it while first reading.

```
    18/02/17 21:59:45 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/uname/input/yarn-site.xml._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1797)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:846)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:503)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:868)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:814)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2603)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1493)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1439)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:444)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1845)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:710)
put: File /user/uname/input/yarn-site.xml._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

**I am not sure why no datanode is running?** I have tried things in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293446/hdfs-error-could-only-be-replicated-to-0-nodes-instead-of-1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271970/hadoop-hdfs-name-is-in-an-inconsistent-state-storage-directoryhadoop-hdfs-data) answer but it didn't work. If you look at the 2nd code block of the question it says that starting the datanode. and logs are written to /home/uname/hadoop-2.9.0/logs/hadoop-uname-datanode-mname.out. I didn't find any error in the log. I am copying the logs below.

```
ulimit -a for user uname
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 63757
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 63757
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

To verify if the data node is really running or not. I executed the very first start command again.

```
sbin/start-df.sh
```

I got following message:

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: namenode running as process 24802. Stop it first.
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/uname/hadoop-2.9.0/logs/hadoop-uname-datanode-mname.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: secondarynamenode running as process 25166. Stop it first.
```

This message says that namenode and secondarynamenode are already running. However, this also doesn't show that datanode is running and it attempts to start datanode again and writes the same log in the log file.

**Any idea why namenode is not starting?**

Comment: Does `jps` show a namenode and datanode? Can you open the namenode web address and see any datanode? Read the log files of the datanode to see if there are errors?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have added the entire content of the log of the datanode logfiles in the question. No datanode process is running.

Comment: Those look like the namenode logs, not the datanode. Also, it's `start-dfs.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to debug the log files from logs directory.
May be you need to delete the Namenode and Datanode Log directories.
Create the Log Directories again.
after that run hadoop namenode format command.
Then run start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh.